# Error during install.package : cannot read unreleased workspace version 3 written by experimental R 3.5.0

Tags: r

I try to install a package in Rstudio with install.package (I don't have internet on the computer, so I try to use a zip download on the CRAN).
I don't understand my error, and I dont find anything on internet about this.

`install.packages("C:/Users/adm_smartcity/Documents/dplyr_0.7.4.zip", repos=NULL)`

The result :

`Installing package into ‘C:/Users/adm_smartcity/Documents/R/win-library/3.4’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified) 
package ‘dplyr’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
Error in readRDS(pfile) : 
  cannot read unreleased workspace version 3 written by experimental R 3.5.0`

(Sorry for my bad english!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whoever produced that zip file used the development version of R to produce it.

Generally binary packages (.zip files on Windows) only work in a particular version of R.  If the binary was built in R x.y.z1, you can only use it in R x.y.z2, where x and y match exactly.  Sometimes it won't work if z1 > z2, but usually the patch level doesn't matter.

If you can't install from source (the .tar.gz file), then you'll need to find someone using the same R version as you (up to x.y) to build a binary for you.